# simulate load-balancer variability

Tags: python, simulation

The following program tries to show how a stateless load balancer creates variability
when spreading balls between bins (with default settings below, the `max/min` ratio is ~2).
Obviously, the more balls we throw, the smaller the spread.

Question: how do I convert it to a continuous example? i.e. instead of using balls, I would like to load balance a "traffic", but I am failing to model this.
My goal is to simulate a behavior showing how load-balanced traffic is spread non-uniformly even using a perfectly uniform sharding function.

````py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import webbrowser

def uniform_bin_filling(balls, bin_len):
  bins = np.zeros(bin_len, dtype=int)
  for i in range(balls):
    bins[np.random.randint(0, bin_len)] += 1

  return bins


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--balls", type=int, default=150)
    parser.add_argument("--bins", type=int, default=10)    
    args = parser.parse_args()

    bins = uniform_bin_filling(args.balls, args.bins)

    print("Expected average is {:.2f}".format(args.balls / args.bins))
    print("The number of balls in each bin is:")
    print(bins)
    r = bins.max() / bins.min()
    print("\nMax/Min ratio: {:.2f}".format(r)) 
```
````

Comment: Replace "ball" with "request/packet"...? Random function will only be approximately uniformly distributed for large executions, not truly round robin

Comment: I can replace it with packets of course. What I do not understand is how I transition from cumulative counts to "load", which should be some sort of derivative of total counts. In other words, with "balls=1000000" the formula above stops showing variability but based on my practical experience there is significant variability in load among upstream backends if we use a sharding function like `HASH(key) % N`.

Comment: Just use modulo on the number directly to get uniform output, not hash